# Difference between 1/0 and 1.0/0.0 in java

Tags: java

I am new in Java programming language, a stupid question comes up as below.

to execute 1/0 in java will be generated a runtime exception, as the value is undefined.

but the 1.0/0.0 will be okay and the value is infinity.

anything special with double data type? could help have a good explanation for understanding? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

> anything special with double data type?

Yes, `double` can represent infinity (as can `float`), whereas `int` can't. The floating point types follow IEEE 754, which allows for signed infinity values, as well as "not a number" (NaN) values, such as trying to obtain the square root of -1.

From [JLS 15.17.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) (division):

> if the value of the divisor in an integer division is 0, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

and

> The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>
> - ...
> - Division of a zero by a zero results in NaN; division of zero by any other finite value results in a signed zero. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.
> - Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity.

Comment: Thank you. your answer make more clarification to my question.